# Problems with React when using SignalR

Tags: javascript, reactjs, logging, signalr, react-big-calendar

I have the following code that I am implementing with SignalR:

Startup:

```
[assembly: OwinStartupAttribute("StartupConfiguration", typeof(AGENDA.Startup))]
    namespace AGENDA
    {
        public class Startup
        {
            public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
            {
                var hubConfiguration = new HubConfiguration();
                hubConfiguration.EnableDetailedErrors = true;
                hubConfiguration.EnableJavaScriptProxies = true;

                app.MapSignalR();
            }
        }
    }
```

Server:
It is where I create the various methods for capturing the server and can receive the information without any problem, however when I send the information from the client, it arrives empty.

```
public class MensajesHub : Hub
    {
        private EventModel _model;
        private bool _modelUpdated = false;
        public void UpdateModel(EventModel clientModel)
        {
            clientModel.LastUpdatedBy = Context.ConnectionId;
            Clients.AllExcept(clientModel.LastUpdatedBy).UpdateMensaje(clientModel);
            UpdateMensaje(clientModel);
        }

        public void UpdateMensaje(EventModel clientModel)
        {
            _model = clientModel;
            _modelUpdated = true;
        }

        [HubMethodName("EnviarMensajes")]
        public static void EnviarMensajes()
        {
            IHubContext context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<MensajesHub>();
            context.Clients.All.updateMessages();
        }
    }
```

It is where I create the various methods for capturing the server and can receive the information without any problem, however when I send the information from the client, it arrives empty.

```
public class EventModel
    {
        [JsonProperty("id_cita")]
        public long Id_Cita { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("descripcion_cita")]
        public string Descripcion_Cita { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("start")]
        public DateTime Start { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("end")]
        public DateTime End { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("id_recurso")]
        public long Id_Recurso { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("recurso_nombre")]
        public string Recurso_Nombre { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("categoria")]
        public int Categoria { get; set; }

        [JsonIgnore]
        public string LastUpdatedBy { get; set; }
    }
```

Client:
I establish the connection with SignalR in this way, which is successful.

```
//SignalR Code
 let mensajes = $.hubConnection();
 //let mensajes = connection;
 console.log(mensajes);
 conexion = this.props.mensajes;
 console.log(conexion);
 conexion.start()
 .done(function (model) {
 conexion.logging = true;
 console.log(conexion);
 console.log('Now connected, connection ID=' + conexion.id);
 updateServerModel();
 })
 .fail(function () {
 conexion.hub.logging = false;
 console.log(conexion);
 console.log('Could not connect');
 });
```

This is where I have the conflict, at first, it brings me the methods of the server, but I can not make the client to pass to the server.

```
function updateServerModel() {
console.log(conexion);
conexion.server.updateMensaje();
console.log(conexion);
conexion.server.updateModel();
console.log(conexion);
console.log(conexion.server);
console.log(conexion);
}
console.log(conexion);
//-------------------------------------
```

But the lines that say Server, never reaches anything, since it says that they are not a function

Any idea that this may happen ... ??? Could anyone help me with this ... ???
Thanks since now....!!!!

Comment: do you have a concrete error message ? Have you read the doc ?

Comment: This is the error: TypeError: 'caller' and 'arguments' are restricted function properties and cannot be accessed in this context. at Function.remoteFunction (<anonymous>:2:26)